# ThisWorkbook Not Working in Excel 2018?

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently encountered a problem where a macro that used to work in previous versions of Excel has stopped functioning as intended. The macro, when functional, opens each file in a specific folder and copies some of its data and pastes it into another file which it opened.

Since this macro is run from within a file in the folder, it was previously programmed to not attempt to re-open the file, using the code below:

```
' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
  '  Set SummarySheet =
    Workbooks.Open ("[Redacted]")
   '     agg_wkb_name = ActiveWorkbook
        lrowcount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("scheduled hours").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("scheduled hours").Range("A2:bz" & lrowcount).Delete
    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    FolderPath = "[Redacted]"

    ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
    NRow = 2

    ' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

    ' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
    Do While FileName <> ""
        ' Open a workbook in the folder
        If FolderPath & FileName = ThisWorkbook.FullName Then
        Set WorkBk = ThisWorkbook
        Else
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName, , True)
        End If
```

However, after our computers and programs were updated to Win10 and Excel 2016, this macro began attempting to also open the workbook running the file ('ThisWorkbook'). When you attempt to say "no, I don't want to re-open the file", it stops the Macro, and when you say "yes", Excel crashes.

I attempted to segregate the code, to pull the data from 'ThisWorkbook' differently than pulling it from the various other workbooks in the folder. The new section of code reads:

```
Do While FileName <> ""
        If Not (FolderPath & FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & ThisWorkbook.Name) Then
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName, , True)
        End If
```

Unfortunately, the very same error still occurs. I'm at a loss - my best guess is that something changed in the way 'ThisWorkbook' functions between the last version of Excel and the current one.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code and watching the values of `FolderPath`, `FileName`, and `ThisWorkbook.FullName`? What are their values during the loop iteration where it attempts to open the workbook?

Comment: Yup, I have. They are what you would expect; at the point they are breaking, they are all identical. Either the 'NOT' isn't working/coded correctly, or the ThisWorkbook function is acting oddly.

Comment: @Graceclaw I'd be easier for us to help if you replace `[Redacted]` with a better example like ``C:\Users\MyUser\Myfolder\``. Often times an issue is because of a missing back slash, listing a full path when you only need the file name, etc...

Comment: @Graceclaw If you're getting the value you expect when watching it, then it sounds like `ThisWorkbook` is doing what it's supposed to do. I'd start to wonder if one of them might have a subtle difference in a non-printing character or something. I don't have a copy of Excel 2016 here to test with, but I might take a stab at it tonight.

Comment: Have you tried...
`Do Until FileName = ""`
    `If FileName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then`
        `Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename, , True)`
    `End If`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that a system administrator had re-mapped the folder to a drive on my computer. I fixed it by not having the code look at the file location for comparison, only the name, since that's all that changes once you get into the folder.

If anyone ever runs into this, or has a similar situation where they are opening all files in a folder except the one that is currently open - don't bother with the filepath. Just use the name.